# Databases from assets folder

Tags: android

How to get data from assets folder db? I have a .db file in my assets folder. Here is what I am doing.

**DBHelper2.class**

```
package com.example.testapp;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

      public class DataBaseHelper2 extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
      private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.testapp/databases/";

      private static String DB_NAME = "birthdate_details.db";

      private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

      private final Context myContext;

      public DataBaseHelper2(Context context) 
      {
          super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
          this.myContext = context;
      }

      public void createDataBase() throws IOException{


    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

      if(dbExist)
      {
          Log.i("DB....", "database available...."+DB_NAME);
      }
      else
      {
          this.getWritableDatabase();

          try {

          copyDataBase();

          } catch (IOException e) {

          throw new Error("Error copying database");

          }

         Log.i("DB..", "database created.....");
       }   

      }


      public boolean checkDataBase(){

      SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

      try{

      String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

      checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

      }catch(SQLiteException e){

          Log.e("CheckDb","DB not found");
      //database does't exist yet.

      if(checkDB != null){

      checkDB.close();

      }
      }
      finally
      {
          if(checkDB != null){

              checkDB.close();

              } 
          this.close();
      }
      return checkDB != null ? true : false;

      }




      private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

      InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

      String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

      OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
          byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

      int length;

      while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){

      myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);

      }

      myOutput.flush();

      myOutput.close();

      myInput.close();

      }

      public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException{

      String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

      return myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

      }


      @Override

      public synchronized void close() {

      if(myDataBase != null)

      myDataBase.close();

      super.close();

      }

      @Override

      public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

      }

      @Override

      public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {


      }  


      public Cursor getData()
      {
          SQLiteDatabase myDB ;
          Cursor cursor ;

                myDB=this.openDataBase();                   

                    cursor=myDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM bdatedetails",null);

                    return cursor;

      }

}
```

**MainActivity.class**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ArrayList<String> AllAssociatedData;
    ListView list;
    DataBaseHelper2 myDbHelper;
    int pos;
    Cursor c;
    ArrayAdapter<String> ad;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    AllAssociatedData = new ArrayList<String>();
    ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, AllAssociatedData);
    list.setAdapter(ad);

    myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper2(this); 
    try 
    {
        myDbHelper.createDataBase();
        c = myDbHelper.getData();

        c.moveToPosition(0);
        AllAssociatedData.add(c.getString(3));
        System.out.println(c.getString(3));
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), c.getString(3), 0).show();
        //ad.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }catch (IOException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
           }

    finally
    {
        myDbHelper.close();
    }

}   
}
```

But the data is not coming.

Also, another problem in internal db table.

**Login.java**

```
public class Login extends Activity {
EditText et1,et2;
Button b;
TextView tv1,tv2,tv3;
MyDatabase mdb;
int count=1;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        et1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        et2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        tv1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv2=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        tv3=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        mdb = new MyDatabase(this);
        mdb.open();


        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                String username=et1.getText().toString();
                String password=et2.getText().toString();
                Cursor c = mdb.getAllUser();
                if(c != null){
                    while(c.moveToNext()==true)
                    {   int id=c.getInt(0);
                        String uname = c.getString(1);
                        String pwd = c.getString(2);
                        long mob=c.getLong(3);
                        String email = c.getString(4);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+id+","+uname+","+pwd+","+mob+","+email,0).show();
                        if(count<=3)
                        {
                        if(username.equals(uname)&&password.equals(pwd))
                        {
                        Intent in=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Welcome.class);
                        in.putExtra("key",uname);
                        mdb.close();
                        c.close();
                        startActivity(in);

                        return;
                        }
                        else
                        {

                        }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Account Blocked",0).show();    
                        }

                    }
                    tv3.setText("No of tries "+count);
                    count++;
                    c.close();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Username/password is incorrect",0).show();
                }

            }
        });
```

**mydatabase.java**

```
public class MyDatabase 
{
private MyHelper mh;
private SQLiteDatabase sdb;

public MyDatabase(Context con)
{
    mh=new MyHelper(con,"UserDetails",null,1);
}
public void open()
{   try{
    sdb=mh.getWritableDatabase();
}
catch(Exception e)
{

}
}
public void insertRegiserUser(String Username,String password,long mobile,String e_mail) 
{
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put("uname",Username);
    cv.put("pwd",password);
    cv.put("mob", mobile);
    cv.put("email",e_mail);
    sdb.insert("login", null,cv);
}

public void updatePwd(String old_pwd,String username,String new_pwd)
{
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put("pwd",new_pwd);
    sdb.update("login", cv,"pwd=? AND uname=?",new String[]{old_pwd,username});
}

public Cursor getAllUser()
{   Cursor c=sdb.query("login",null,null,null,null,null,null);
    return c;

}
class MyHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{ 


    public MyHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,
            int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("Create table login(_id integer primary key, uname text unique, pwd text, mob long, email text);");

    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
public void close(){
    sdb.close();
}
}
```

Comment: what's in the logcat?

Comment: try this http://zaman91.wordpress.com/2010/09/22/android-how-to-use-own-sqlite-database/